# 64 bit python is building a 32 bit COM server

Tags: python, vba, com, 32bit-64bit, pywin32

```py
import platform 
platform.architecture() #('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

I'm running on 64 bit, specifically:
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit
(AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`

I created a COM server which I'd like to call from a 64 bit client:

```py
class HelloWorld:
    # pythoncom.CreateGuid()
    _reg_clsid_ = "{E32B2663-BD8C-472A-AC96-142AE4665FD7}"
    _reg_desc_ = "MyLib COM server"
    _reg_progid_ = "MyLib.HelloWorld"

    _public_methods_ = ["Hello"]
    _public_attrs_ = ["softspace", "noCalls"]
    _readonly_attrs_ = ["noCalls"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.softspace = 1
        self.noCalls = 0

    def Hello(self, who):
        self.noCalls = self.noCalls + 1
        # insert "softspace" number of spaces
        return "Hello" + " " * self.softspace + str(who)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(HelloWorld)
```

*Registered using: `python server.py` - (call the `__main__` method to register the server)*

From a 64 bit COM client (Excel VBA), I am unable to create an instance

```vb
Sub t()
    Dim a As Object
    Set a = CreateObject("MyLib.HelloWorld")
End Sub
```

I get

> Module not found

I can in python 64 bit

```py
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
c = CreateObject('MyLib.HelloWorld')
```

I can in a 32 bit VBA host.
I'm guessing my python server is being declared 32 bit, python comtypes *just works<sup>TM</sup>* regardless of server bitness.

Comment: Module not found (0x8007007E) has nothing to do with x64 vs x86. What likely happens is the client process (Excel, etc.) cannot find pythoncomXX.dll, pythonXX.dll, etc because the COM registration only writes "pythoncomXX.dll" in the registry. You can check that using the procmon tool from sysinternals (filter only file events, and by your process name). You want to make sure these are in the path. (honestly I don't understand how python works, I have tons of different python installation on my PC for some reason, none of them in the path...)

Comment: There's other recent questions on Python / COM in the com channel.You can create from 32-bit because it's running out of process and is running python.exe. However, when running in process, as it would try under 64-bits, it can't resolve the Python runtime as Simon wrote.There's Python DLLs. and then the MS Visual C++ runtime that Python uses on Windows...that's my experience the little I've looked into it.

Comment: The fact that pythoncom registers for inproc & outproc by default (note you can override it with _reg_clsctx_ https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/server.html) carries its own set of testing issues, false positive, etc. IMHO it's a bad design decision.

Comment: @SimonMourier ah, ok, lemme check I understand: so for 64 bit where it will run in proc using the `pythoncomXX.dll` rather than out of proc using pythonXX.exe + local server.py, then the aforementioned DLL for the server needs to be added to the path? Do you think this is because I use an anaconda python installation so the path is modified at runtime by activating the conda environment but Excel does not know to do that? That would explain why Python 64 works but not Excel, as python is being run within the conda environment.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson see above, is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Registration for 64 bit and registration for 32 bit are located in different places (there's never any outproc/localserver fallback from 32=>64 or 64=>32). In your case, you only register for 64 bit, with inproc, so it will try to load pythoncomXX.dll and fail. If you go in HKCR\CLSID\{E32B2663-BD8C-472A-AC96-142AE4665FD7} and remove the "InprocServer32 key it will work but outproc only because LocalServer32 register a fullpath to pythonw.exe. If you want inproc, you must fix the .dll path. If you want only outproc, add `_reg_clsctx_ = comtypes.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` in your code

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for your help I think I'm getting it. Inproc I should fix the path to `pythoncomXX.dll` to make it fully qualified (so `C:\WINDOWS\system32\pythoncom38.dll`? - just tried, didn't work) What about `pythonXX.dll` you mentioned in the first comment? Also to be clear _"Registration for 64 bit and registration for 32 bit are located in different places"_ - but 32 bit can still use my 64 bit server through outproc com marshalling right? Is it the inproc server registration that is different locations because those aren't cross compatible?

Comment: I personally don't have any python dll in windows\system32 (I have it for 64 bit clients in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32) and yes, it requires others dll (like python37.dll, etc.) to be findable (in the path, etc.). If you want to make sure your COM server works for all clients, you must register for 32 and 64 bit registries, inproc and/or outproc (that is COM requirement). If you register in both registries with outproc, it should be able to server both 32 and 64 clients, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232167/discussion-between-greedo-and-simon-mourier).

Comment: If you don't need inproc performance you can delete the key for the inproc server and the out of process server will work under 64 bits. I will go out on a limb and say you don't have to specifically register for both keys for out of proc. The system just finds it. You didn't have to do anything to get it to run under 32-bit VBA (or VBS) did you? One way to test is to write a single VBS script that creates your object. Run it with c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe and also c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe to test 64-bit and 32-bit respectively.